# Changing DHCPv6 server

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, dhcp-server, isc-dhcp

I have a DHCPv6 daemon that is answering for requests of some machines and everything is working fine. So I decided to remove this DHCPv6 daemon e start another daemon on another server, but the problem now is that since all machines already have a long lease, they don't ask to renew the lease or to get a new lease. I know the solution would be restarting machines, restarting clients, using dhclient -r to release the lease, etc. But I can't do that, I only have the control of the new installed DHCPv6 server, is there any way to make DHCPv6 daemon to actively advertise to the clients something like that ? I'm using the ISC DHCP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you must perform a manual refresh/restart on the client or simply wait for the lease to be updated at 50% of the lease lifetime. This should not present a problem.

If you are concerned that the new server will issue conflicting adresses, see IP Address Conflict Prevention in the dhcpd.conf man page.

Comment: So if I don't have control over the client I'll have to wait for the lease to expire ? What I want was to do something to force the client to get the IP from that new DHCPv6 server, but I'm starting to think that this wouldn't be possible from the new DHCPv6 server.

Comment: There is no way to force refresh of the clients from the server in DHCP 4 or 6.